# How can I discover and master the technical system of an ERP and/or a framework published by the company that has just hired me?

Tags: frameworks, erp

How can I discover and master the technical system of an ERP and/or a framework published by the company that has just hired me?

For example: is it useful to draw UML diagrams on paper (and if so, which ones?)? What notes on paper to take?

Comment: Use whatever works best for you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Engineering. We only support [good](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions. [Many sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have [different rules](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067). Feel free to take your issue to an appropriate site if one exists. Search existing answers first. Edit your question to fit the sites needs. Please [don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) by failing to delete your question here.

Comment: @candied_orange sorry! (I can't delete the question since it's answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start new positions or teams with a learning plan. I usually add to the existing documentation or start new sections. Often, I set myself a deliverable to revise the new engineer documentation.

I think it's important to focus on the content rather than the diagram type. Depending on the situation, one of the following might be most useful:

1. Components and their interactions
2. Data flow
3. Data structures
4. Algorithms (how the key problem is solved)

I try not to do anything on paper. I try to develop skills and have the tools to do a rough version electronically. Ideally it should go into a wiki of some sort. I use yEd for graphs. But it really matters you have a tool you are comfortable with and can interview someone and take notes at the same time.

Depending on the language, there may be tools to assist you with getting an overview. For example, class dependency or layer diagrams generated by the IDE or a tool.

I start out with asking my mentor or manager about a list of people to learn from. I ask for an architecture overview, usually on a whiteboard, on how the component(s) that are their domain work. Sometimes a code walk-through can help you get started. I usually have a list of questions prepared, for example problem areas and the One Wish (if you had one wish regardless of constraints to change about your project, what would it be)

It's not a set process. Initially you will not know what you don't know thus once starting to learn you will discover more things you don't know.